# Not able to customize bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to customize the calendar, but it seems that it is not taking into account the customization, such as displaying the today button or ignoring past dates. I tried the following:
in the head

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in the top body

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Then in the form:

```
    <script>
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            startDate: 0,
            todayBtn: "linked"
        });
    </script>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date *" id="caldate" required data-validation-required-message="Please choose date.">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>
            </span>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, I still do not get the 'Today' button. I am not sure if the reason is because the javascript code is not correct? (not calling the calendar correctly) or misplaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your jQuery call with `todayBtn` option isn't really pointing to your input.  The datepicker functionality you're seeing is based on your html.  I moved the script after the elements (so it runs after the target elements are in the DOM) and changed the jQuery call to find the correct element.  Also, I believe the `startDate` option should be a date so I changed it from `0` to `'3/16/2016'`.  The original html is unchanged...

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
      placeholder="Date *" id="caldate" required data-validation-required-message="Please choose date.">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>
    </span>
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $("div.input-group.date").datepicker({
    startDate: '3/1/2016',
    todayBtn: "linked"
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I cannot change the class name because it is linked to other input in the same form... Is that the only paramter we can use to designate the element in the $('.element') ?

Comment: I should've mentioned that my example code, the jQuery call $('.date') finds my input because my input's class is "date".  Your original example doesn't have any elements with class="datepicker" which probably partially accounts for why your todayBtn option didn't have any effect.

Comment: I changed it to $('.form-control') but still nothing... I am really confused

Comment: I think the two main problems with your original code is that your .datepicker call with todayBtn is 1) before the elements which means that the code will run and not find anything since the elements are there yet and 2) $('.datepicker') attempts to find any elements where class="datepicker" which you didn't have.  I moved the <script> tag after the <div>'s and changed the jQuery selector to "div.input-group.date" so it finds your element properly.

Comment: Ok problem halfway solved: Today's button shows up, but the startDate:0 not working yet. The goal is to disable any past date.

Comment: I see.  The startDate option needs to be a date of some sort.  I'm modifying the answer to reflect...